# Maintaining form-inline Bootstrap form inline when browser resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `form-inline` `Bootstrap` `form` in my `ASP.NET` `MVC` View:

```
<div class="home-search">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class="form-inline", @role = "search"}))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="enter a title name..." required>
                <select name="t" class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="auto">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="movies">Movies</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
        }
</div>
```

...and this accompanying `CSS`:

```
.home-search form {    
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.home-search input, .home-search select, .home-search button {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

When minimizing the browser, the three controls of the form stack vertically, which is how Bootstrap works. How can I however keep the elements of the form in one line and just have them automatically resize to fit the screen? Are `@media` queries the way to go here or am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/mayoru

Yes, media query and a custom class. The min-width: 350px is because that specific form looks good inline until about 320px. When you add the gutter -- 15px on either side of the .container (30px) it's 350px.  Since the smallest device is 240px, under that is full width or it starts looking bad. The max-width:767px is so as to not over-write the default styling that kicks in at 768px min-width.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    
  <form class="form-inline custom-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="enter a title name..." required>
                <select name="t" class="form-control selectpicker" data-width="auto">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="movies">Movies</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
    </div>
    

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-form .form-control {
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
.custom-form .btn .fa {
    line-height: 0px
}
@media (min-width:350px) and (max-width:767px) { 
    .custom-form .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .custom-form .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christina, exactly what I was looking for. Awesome explanation too!